# MATLAB Crashes During the Timer Object Deletion

Tags: matlab, scheduling

I have created two timer objects in MATLAB with TasksToExecute equals to inf. I start these two timers with start method and everything works well.
I want to delete the available timer objects  after I press ctrl+c in the command window (or even in the main.m script before the timers start):

1. stop(timerfind) ---> this works well
2. delete(timerfind) ---> MATLAB crashes

The problem: when I want to delete the timer objects, MATLAB crashes!

Also, when I want to execute the "clear all" command in my code, MATLAB crashes!

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Set-up: Windows 10, MATLAB 2017b

Comment: You might want to report this bug to MathWorks.

Comment: is the timer running any mex code?  or anything that wouldn't be classed as standard Matlab code?  Also have you considered that `clear all` might be deleting the timer while its running which will probably cause an issue.  FYI you rarely if **ever** need to use `clear all`

Comment: Yes, a mex-code is running in one of the timers! What should I do about it?!

Comment: You will need to wait until the mex code is finished before you stop the timer.  MEX code crashing can often cause matlab to crash.

Comment: How can you check whether a mex-code is running by writing a MATLAB script? and, how to stop it from the script?!

Answer (score 2):

The solution I am currently using is adding a short pause between stop and delete.

It's a kind of a patch, and I am not sure if it's going to work for you.

My code looks as follows:

```
all_timers = timerfindall();
if (~isempty(all_timers))
    stop(all_timers);
    pause(0.1);  % <--- Add a short pause between stop and delete

    for i = 1:length(all_timers)
        delete(all_timers(i));
    end
end
```

The above code stops and deletes all the timers.
I am deleting all, because in cases where the program terminates before deleting the timer (like debugging), the "redundant" timers objects remains undeleted.

I am not sure why the pause prevents the crash.
I guess that the pause allows "context switch", and lets the timer callback function finish execution, before deleting the timer.

Comment: I have tried pause() in the first place but nothing happened!

Comment: Does the callback function of the timer keeps running when you delete the timer?

Comment: No, It is not working, seemingly... Because I have fprintf() for debugging!

Comment: Are there any other asynchronous executions like other timers or GUI callbacks that keep running?

Comment: Are you sure the callback function existed? To make sure, try placing `fprintf()` at the beginning and at the end of the function. make sure the delete is not in between.

Answer (score 0):

Just opened MATLAB software with "Run as Administrator" and the problem solved!
Maybe, objects deletion needs administrator privileges!

Comment: Did you verify that with a simple case? Just create a Timer object (that does nothing), and then delete it (without administrator privileges)?

Comment: Yes, I just commented the mex-code and tried without it, but it crashed again.